# PhoneGap and SBJSON duplicate conflict while using Facebook iOS SDK

Tags: json, facebook, ios, cordova

I'm trying to use the Facebook iOS SDK, but it requires SBJSON, which is already included by PhoneGap, thus raising ld: duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_SBJSON.

PhoneGap 0.9.3 
iOS SDK 4.2

Does anyone have any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Hello, did you find a solution for this? I'm having similar problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I too faced the same problem, i just deleted the 'JSON' folder inside the 'FBConnect' folder. Then it worked fine .